# A probability problem determining elements in certain order

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> $3$ persons $A,B,C$ are to speak at a function along with $7$ other persons.If they speak at random order, what is the probability that $A$ speaks before $B$ and $B$ speaks before $C\ ?$.

**My solution**: $A,B,C$ and $7$ other people so a total of $10$ speakers. The number of ways in which $10$ people can speak at random is $10!$.Since $A$ speaks before $B$ and $B$ speaks before $C$ so I consider $ABC$ as a unit. So, total $8$ units. $8$ units can speak in $8!$ ways.

So, the desired probability is ${{8!}\over{10!}}={1\over {90}}. $

Now I have doubt.The order does not necessarily have to be $ABC.$ It could be $..A...B...C..$ In that case the numerator shall change to $\binom{10}{3}\times 7! .$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

Under the interpretation that 'speaking before' means 'speaking at some point before' (like you do in the second part of your post), rather than 'speaking directly before' (like you do in the first part of your post), you can make your life a lot easier by simply considering the order of $A$ $B$, and $C$ as they appear *somewhere* in the line-up.  For example, line-up:

$$AGDHFCBEJI$$

can be seen as:

$$A....CB...$$

and thus as:

$$ACB$$

There are $6$ such orders ($ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CAB,CBA$), only $1$ of which is the one you are looking for. And since by symmetry each order is equally likely, the probability is:

$$\frac{1}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Out of 10 spots, choose any 3. A will go before B, B before C in those 3 spots. 7 spots remain which can be filled in 7! ways by the remaining speakers.